# Iterating over a Map with template in Polymer

Tags: ajax, dictionary, polymer, iron

I tested Polymer yesterday. Its quite cool, but I wonder how I can read a Map with `<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{binding}}">`. Is this possible?

I created an ajax-call to a read url where I get a `Map<String,List<String>>` as response. I want to render the keys as radio-button-group and the value-list-items as members of this radio-button group.
Atm I don't know how to archieve this. Does anyone have a hint how I could solve this issue with polymer and iron/paper elements?

Thnx

Comment: I'd recommend you to redesign your Objects. Even though it should be possible to achieve what you want but it will not be dynamically generated. `dom-repeat` requires `key` to be same for all the objects, but in your case you are going to have unique key. So as a result you will have to write each `radio-group` in your HTML rather then depending upon dynamic generation.

Comment: I see, then is it possible to create an ajax get-request with given key-parameter and use the ajax-response in a dom-repeat template? If so, I could loop over a "radio-group-keys-array" and call this ajax request and use the response to render the radio-buttons for this group.

Comment: Not clear on what you are saying, but if you are saying that you'll use your `dom-repeat` over `List<String>` only(doesn't matter what you get from `ajax` request) then yes it is possible.